# cumcount reverse for dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe column as

```
data = {'cumcount':[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

But I want the cumcounts in reverse order as such ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWU1D.png))

```
expected = {'expected':[3,2,1,0,5,4,3,2,1,0,2,1,0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding and reordering the columns for sorting decisions.

```
df['flg'] = df['cumcount'].eq(0).cumsum()
df.sort_values(['flg','cumcount'], ascending=([True, False]))

    cumcount    flg
3   3   1
2   2   1
1   1   1
0   0   1
9   5   2
8   4   2
7   3   2
6   2   2
5   1   2
4   0   2
12  2   3
11  1   3
10  0   3
```